# Generate ASMX wrapper over WSDL via apache cxf

Tags: java, soap, cxf, asmx

We have implemeted a `SOAP` web service via `Apache CXF` (java). Now our client wants to get `ASMX` wrapper over its `WSDL`. Any ideas?